# What is appropriate way to generate hash in JavaScript having values as array

Tags: javascript, hash

I wanted to generate dictionary like below

```
a = {'A' => [1,2,3], 'B' => [12,13], 'C' => [32,432]}

var h = {}
gen_h(['A', 1])
gen_h(['A', 2])
gen_h(['B', 13])
gen_h(['C', 32])
gen_h(['C', 432])
```

should give h value as -

```
h = {'A' => [1,2], 'B' => [13], 'C' => [32,432]}
```

Comment: `function gen_h(['A', 1])`?  Shouldn't this just be `gen_h(['A', 1])`?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Did you mean *generating an object* instead of *generating hash*? I would call a hash something generated by a *hash function*, like MD5. Also, what has `a` to do with all of this?

Comment: @FelixKling.. Sorry but i am looking for `key` `value` `pair` `hash` not MD5 hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just normal JavaScript, nothing to do with jQuery.

```
function gen_h(data){
    var key = data[0], // key
        val = data[1]; // value
    if(!h[key]){       // does hash exist?
        h[key] = [];
    }
    h[key].push(val);  // add value
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var h = {};
gen_h(['A', 1]);
gen_h(['A', 2]);
gen_h(['B', 13]);
gen_h(['C', 32]);
gen_h(['C', 432]);
```